# Create image from UIView with video feed

Tags: ios, opengl-es, dji-sdk

I have implemented DJI Mobile SDK, which can transmit video from drone. SDK accepts `UIView` as parametr for drawing video (it probably use OpenGL in background to drawing video frames inside `UIView`)

I need to grab each frame from this video as `CIImage` for `Vision Kit` but I don't how video is encoded etc.. I have tried to create "screenshot" of this `UIView` but without success. Screenshot doesn't contains video.

How can I create "raw" screenshot of any `UIView` with some low-end drawing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will pull a screenshot from the top UIView.

```
    //Take Screenshot
    let screenshot = self.view?.pb_takeSnapshot()
    
    //Save Image
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

    guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: screenshot!) else {
        fatalError("couldn't convert uiimage to CIImage")
    }
    detect(image: ciImage)
```